# Counting { and } braces in program JAVA

Tags: java, count

I have to read an input file that contains codes and produce an output that matches the corresponding braces ({ and })

example of how output will look

```
import java.util.scanner;
public class Tester {1
 public static void main(String[] args) {2
 Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
 int price = in.nextInt;
 if (price < 10)
 System.out.println("Good price");
 System.out.println ("Buy it");
 }2
 }1
 }0
}0
```

0 will represent extra braces that has no matches.
What is the most efficient way to approach this?
Should I just process line by line with Strings?

Comment: can you show your approach ?

Comment: Although the question is not clear enough for me.
The easiest way to check for braces is to use a stack .. 
1- when you find a left brace push it
2- when you find a right brace, pop one item from the stack

If the stack is empty when you finish processing, then you have the right numbers of braces ..

Comment: So my initial thought process is that I go line by line with Strings.

Comment: so While (input.hasNextLine())
{
  String line=input.nextLine();
if line.contains("{")
{ Counter++;
}
if line.contains("}")
{Counter--;
}

The idea is to increase counter with all { braces then decrease it with } braces.

Comment: Please use post edit to put your thoughts in the question, not just comment it, especially with many codes.

Comment: sorry new to this site

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a `count`. Iterate the characters in every line, increment (or decrement) the `count` and (output the `count`) for `{` and `}` respectively. Don't forget to `close` your `Scanner` with a `finally` block or a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Assuming your file `Tester.java` is in the user's home folder you could do something like,

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Tester.java");
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(f)) {
    int count = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        for (char ch : line.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.print(ch);
            if (ch == '{') {
                System.out.print(++count);
            } else if (ch == '}') {
                if (count > 0) {
                    System.out.print(--count);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(count);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what (char ch : line.toCharArray()) does?

Comment: It's a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) over the `char[]` returned by [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I didn't expect it to be so simple, guess I got some reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the extra braces by making use of stack as below:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    File file = new File("InputFile");
    int lineCount = 0;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineCount++;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if (line.charAt(i) == '{') {
                    stack.push("{");
                } else if (line.charAt(i) == '}') {
                    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                        stack.pop();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Extra brace found at line number : " + lineCount);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(stack.size() + " braces are opend but not closed ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```